# onEdit() trigger to delete edited cells eventId and then create new one

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have the following script that when called will create events in a google calendar based on inputs from google sheets. The function 'onOpen()' and 'scheduleShifts()' functions work as expected, if you have any improvements I'd be more than happy to implement them.

```
function onOpen(){
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu("Sync to Calendar")
  menu.addItem("Schedule Shifts Now", "scheduleShifts")
  menu.addToUi();
}

function scheduleShifts(){

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:D12").getValues();

  for (let x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var volunteer = shift[2];
    var eventId = shift[3];
    
    if (eventId == ""){
    var newEvent = eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
    var newEventId = newEvent.getId();
    spreadsheet.getRange(8 + x, 4).setValue(newEventId); 
  }
  }
}
```

The issue I have is based on the onEdit() trigger, I want the trigger to delete the eventId that corresponds to the edited data, in this case, it is simply the title of the event, and then create a new event based on the edited data. However, when I edit data from the cell array nothing is changed in the google calendar. Any help for this issue would be appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e){

  var editedData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(8, 3, 1, 5).getValues()[2];
  var event = editedData[3]
   try{
//      print(event);
      event.deleteEventSeries();
      shift[3] = '';
    }
    catch(e){
    }
  }
```

For clarity on google sheets the columns are: Start Time/ End Time / Volunteer / EventID. with the data being from cell range A8:D12

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The issue I have is based on the onEdit() trigger, I want the trigger to delete the eventId that corresponds to the edited data, in this case, it is simply the title of the event, and then create a new event based on the edited data. However, when I edit data from the cell array nothing is changed in the google calendar`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: essentially the onEdit() trigger would be in use when any cell in a section of the spreadsheet are edited, in the code I did that would be the line:

 var editedData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(8, 3, 1, 5).getValues()[2]

Through research, I thoguth that upon the onEdit() trigger being activated the next line of code would be called, whereby the current event would be deleted, however nothing is changing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that `var editedData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(8, 3, 1, 5).getValues()[2]` is `undefined`. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? For example, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: here is the link to the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hNOR_FjNBtQsn16uFFXWJ31NLCD_VIttKAe6nXccMtg/edit?usp=sharing
The goal was essentially when the (8,3,1,5) section of the spreadsheet would be edited, which would cause the onEdit() trigger to activate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize. When I tried to open your sample Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I cannot open it. I apologize for this.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hNOR_FjNBtQsn16uFFXWJ31NLCD_VIttKAe6nXccMtg/edit?usp=sharing
This should work, thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could open your sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I have a question. In your goal, for example, when one of the rows from 8 to 12 is edited, you want to delete the event using the event ID of the column "E" from the Calendar. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hello, yes that would be correct, use event ID in column 'E' and delete the already created event in google calendar as well as the event ID column 'E' if an edit is made in column 'D', then upon running the menu item 'Schedule Shifts' a new event and event ID would be generated based on the edit

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Main issues:

- You are using a simple trigger, which cannot be used to access services that require authorization (see [Simple Triggers > Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)).
- The `onEdit` function is not checking whether the edited cell is in the right range.
- The `onEdit` function is not retrieving the calendar event, just an `undefined` value, because the array `e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(8, 3, 1, 5).getValues()` has only one element.

#### Solution:

- [Install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) your `onEdit` trigger. You can do that manually, following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or programmatically, by executing `installTrigger` once (see the code sample below).
- Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to check which cell was edited before deleting the corresponding event.
- Call [CalendarApp.getEventById(iCalId)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#geteventbyidicalid) to get the calendar event you want to retrieve.

#### Code sample:

```
function installTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEditTrigger")
           .forSpreadsheet(ss)
           .onEdit()
           .create();
}

function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var FIRST_ROW = 8; // First row to check
  var LAST_ROW = 12; // Last row to check
  var TITLE_COL = 3; // Column index where to check changes
  var ID_COL = 5; // Column index with event id
  var colIndex = range.getColumn();
  var rowIndex = range.getRow();
  if (colIndex === TITLE_COL && rowIndex >= FIRST_ROW && rowIndex <= LAST_ROW) {
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    var eventIdRange = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, ID_COL);
    var eventId = eventIdRange.getValue();
    var event = CalendarApp.getEventById(eventId);
    event.deleteEvent();
    eventIdRange.setValue("");
  }
}
```

#### Other issues:

In the spreadsheet you provided, the eventId's are located in column E, but according to `scheduleShifts`, they are in column D (corresponding to `Description` in your spreadsheet). I'd suggest you to modify your function accordingly:

```
function scheduleShifts(){

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:E12").getValues();

  for (let x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var volunteer = shift[2];
    var description = shift[3];
    var eventId = shift[4];
    
    if (eventId == ""){
      var newEvent = eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
      var newEventId = newEvent.getId();
      spreadsheet.getRange(8 + x, 5).setValue(newEventId); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for the response, I've made the amendments to the code as well as researched the calls. It's been said online that the call: CalendarApp.getEventById() has a bug that will return null, I added a log and that was the case. I'm not sure whether this is a mistake on my part or this is simply something that won't work. 
Cheers

Comment: @MangoFanatic1337 If you try to log Apps Script built-in objects like Event, it's normal that you get `{}`. The fact that you are not getting any error when calling `event.deleteEvent();` implies that `event` is not null. Also, the sample code I provided is working for me, so, apart from this logging "null", are you getting any problem? Is the event getting removed from the calendar, as desired?

Comment: @MangoFanatic1337 Also, can you clarify where did you read `It's been said online that the call: CalendarApp.getEventById() has a bug that will return null`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Upon having a logger on eventId it was giving out the correct values. However, upon calling the deleteEventById, it would return the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteEvent' of null
    at onEditTrigger(Code_4:48:11). Logically, it should've deleted the event since it has got the correct value for the ID but the above error is constant. I'm not sure what the root cause of this could be so any ideas would be much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151142698, this was the link to the bug

Comment: upon checking it seems that I still need to give authorisation for the trigger to work properly using the scope :https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events. I've checked online and the method was using appscript.json, and authorise from there,m however the structure on the googlecloud forums and the script itself is quite different, so any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: @MangoFanatic1337 You don't need to add that scope explicitly if you haven't added [explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) to your manifest file, since the script automatically detects what scopes are necessary otherwise.

Comment: @MangoFanatic1337 About the issue you referenced, it was closed as intended behavior since they were not getting the ID from the appropriate place. If you are getting the ID from `newEvent.getId();`, it should work (and it definitely works for me). Are you sure the user who edits the spreadsheet (and so triggers `onEditTrigger`) has access to this event?

Comment: Hey, the newEvent.getId(); works successfully as I am able to get the event ID when generating the initial events. It is simply the CalendarApp.getEventById(); has an issue. I checked if the input type was correct and it is of type string, as is needed, but still, the output is the above error that I had mentioned. I feel that the issue is accessing the events, because even when I am editing them it simply doesn't work and I am the one that created the calendar and spreadsheet linked to the said calendar. If you have any further suggestions please do not hesitate.

Comment: @MangoFanatic1337 `I feel that the issue is accessing the events, because even when I am editing them it simply doesn't work` Can you provide more details about this? What `doesn't work` means in this case? Are you able to access those events via Calendar UI?

Comment: @MangoFanatic1337 Btw, by `If you are getting the ID from newEvent.getId();` I meant that, since you are getting the `ID` from that place, `CalendarApp.getEventById()` should work, as long as the executing user is the same account as the one who wrote the `ID` to the spreadsheet. I never implied `newEvent.getId();` was not working.